# mvc4 project with facebook but the externalloginconfirmation textboxes give the Previous values for last user

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, browser, asp.net-membership

I have mvc project with facebook login it works fine but when the ExternalLoginCallback action return the externalloginconfirmation view
the username textbox show the Previous values for last user not the Current User`s value

**and when I inspect the textbox I saw the right value on the page source code**

**and when I change the browser the value is right**

here is the ExternalLoginCallback  code

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {

            AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
            if (!result.IsSuccessful)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
            }

            if (OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // If the current user is logged in add the new account
                OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, User.Identity.Name);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                // User is new, ask for their desired membership name
                // User is new, ask for their desired membership name
                string loginData = OAuthWebSecurity.SerializeProviderUserId(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId);
                ViewBag.ProviderDisplayName = OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData(result.Provider).DisplayName;
                ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;




                    //to get the user email

                var fb = new FacebookClient(result.ExtraData["accesstoken"]);
                dynamic myInfo = fb.Get("/me?fields=email"); // specify the email field
               var UserEmail = myInfo.email;





                var model = new RegisterExternalLoginModel { UserName = result.UserName, Email = UserEmail, ExternalLoginData = loginData };


                return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", model);
            }

        }
```

and this is the externalloginconfirmation action code

```
  [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult ExternalLoginConfirmation(RegisterExternalLoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            string provider = null;
            string providerUserId = null;

            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || !OAuthWebSecurity.TryDeserializeProviderUserId(model.ExternalLoginData, out provider, out providerUserId))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Manage");
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Insert a new user into the database
                using (UsersContext db = new UsersContext())
                {
                    UserProfile user = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.ToLower() == model.UserName.ToLower());
                    // Check if user already exists
                    if (user == null)
                    {
                        // Insert name into the profile table
                        db.UserProfiles.Add(new UserProfile { UserName = model.UserName,Email=model.Email });
                        db.SaveChanges();

                        OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(provider, providerUserId, model.UserName);
                        OAuthWebSecurity.Login(provider, providerUserId, createPersistentCookie: false);

                        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "User name already exists. Please enter a different user name.");
                    }
                }
            }

            ViewBag.ProviderDisplayName = OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData(provider).DisplayName;
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View(model);
        }
```

and this is the externalloginconfirmation view

```
<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
    <h2>Associate your @ViewBag.ProviderDisplayName account.</h2>
</hgroup>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLoginConfirmation", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Association Form</legend>
        <p>
            You've successfully authenticated with <strong>@ViewBag.ProviderDisplayName</strong>.
            Please enter a user name for this site below and click the Confirm button to finish
            logging in.
        </p>
        <ol>
            <li class="name">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </li>
            <li class="Email">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)

            </li>
        </ol>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ExternalLoginData)
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </fieldset>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in your browser coockie check if you have an bad extensions program to save your data in an other coockie beside .aspxauth and try to clear your coockie